# Understanding Swift default valued properties inside a Protocol extension

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, macos, swift-protocols

I have this sample protocol having a default valued property with extension.

```
protocol SampleProtocol{
    var sample:String?{get set}
}
extension SampleProtocol{
    var sample:String?{ get { return nil } set{} }
}
```

Now, my TestClass implements SampleProtocol as below.

```
class TestClass:SampleProtocol {
    var sample: String?{
        return "TestClass"
    }
}
```

And there's one helper method that prints a sample value from the SampleProtocol.

```
func printValue(_ value: SampleProtocol){
    print(value.sample)
}
```

Now the problem is

```
let testObj = TestClass()
print(testObj.sample) // prints "TestClass"
printValue(testObj) // prints nil
```

From the above result, I need to understand why when the testObj is typecasted into SampleProtcol, it is considering default implementation from extension instead of the implementation from the TestClass?

Comment: You are creating a new computed var inside the TestClass rather than using protocol var.. try this ```var sample: String? = "TestClass"``` inside  the TestClass.

Comment: I don’t know the underlying reason for this but it doesn’t work because you have a computed property in your class, if you change it to a stored property you will get the expected behavior

Comment: wow, changing `sample`  into stored property worked out well.
I mean any explanation or Swift doc if you guys know for this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `TestClass` is not implementing the `SampleProtocol` so when you pass it in the `printValue` method that takes a `SampleProtocol`, it will call the default implementation in the protocol extension(since the instance you pass does not implement the protocol method).

In the `SampleProtocol` you have defined the variable as {get set} but in the `TestClass` variable you have only provided a getter, this does not match the requirements (If you remove the protocol extension you will see an error that the class does not conform to the protocol).

It will work if you provide a setter:

```
class TestClass: SampleProtocol {
    var sample: String? {
        get {
        return "TestClass"
        } set { }
    }
}
```